# Entity Framework 6 with SQLite 1.0.108.0 query hangs forever

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sqlite, .net-4.0

We have an x86-bit winforms application that is .Net 4.0 and using EF 6.2
and SQLite 1.0.108.0.

Application is running fine on most machines on some it just hangs forever when querying any table in sqlite db file.

We are able to create the context, but after calling the first query it just hangs.

Also, calling `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` hangs forever too.

Also worth mentioning that using `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection` and `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand` works fine.

There are no prior calls to db through EF context, so there should not be any lingering connection to DB that is still not disposed.

My context class is:

```
public class MyClientContext : DbContext
{
    static MyClientContext ()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyClientContext >(new 
        CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyClientContext >());
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new EncryptedConnectionFactory();
    }

    public eReceiptPosClientContext(string connectionString)
    : base(Database.DefaultConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(connectionString), true)
    {
    }

   // DBsets here

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       // Mappings here
   }
}
```

EF and SQLite configs in App.Config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>



<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description="Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

**Update:**

I am sure now that it is an issue with Disposing the repository object. I think calling the object dispose is not disposing anything really.

Thats why calling GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() hangs.

Below is how I create and use the repo:

```
using (var repo = new SettingsRepository(dbConnString))
{
    repo.GetValue(HasValidReceiptsKey);
}
```

And inside `GetValue()`:

```
return _db.Settings.Where(k => k.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Can it really be that the dispose is not working?

Or am I missing something.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Mousa Shawar

Comment: how many people are connecting to this db concurrently?

Comment: Just one (my application) @JohnB

Comment: show example code of how you get records from db